# Teradata / Aster: How do i setup tab delimited output when using ACT tool of Aster DB?

Tags: teradata-aster

I want to export aster tables into tab delimited files, each file containing just 100 records. Hence i'm using ACT Tool as i cannot specify an SQL (`select * from table_name limit 100`) with ncluster_export tool.
One issue i'm facing is when specifying the -F option with ACT tool, i am not able to specify TAB as the delimiter.
I have tried '\t' and 'TAB', which did not resolve to correct TAB.
I have checked the guide and act --help, couldn't find the correct option.

**My commands have been like:**

`act -h xx.xx.xx.xx -U <<username>> -w <<password>> -p <<port> -d mintdw  -t -F "\t" -A -c "select * from <<tablename>> limit 100;" -o /tmp/filename`

Please help me out.
Closest post on SE i found was :  [Teradata / Aster : Fast Export / ncluster_export using query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499115/teradata-aster-fast-export-ncluster-export-using-query)

Comment: just guess: -F "   " (tab inside"") - wont help?

Comment: how would i type a tab inside the double quote ? This is a command on the terminal. If i press tab, it would'nt type a tab.

Comment: so bypass it by writing TAB in some editor and copy-paste to terminal ;). Just make sure the terminal do not convert your tab into sequence of spaces

Comment: Thanks xhudik for the idea, I could not try that out as we moved out of Aster Database using CSVs.
ncluster_export turned out to be the fastest tool to export data